# How do I execute commands after deployment in Elasticbeanstalk

Tags: php, laravel, amazon-web-services, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I have Laravel project and .ebextensions in the root.

After deployment I need to execute

`sudo chmod -R 777 storage`

`php artisan passport:install`

I made ****.config file in the .ebextensions directory.

But I dont know how to execute `sudo` commands.

How to fix this?

Comment: You perhaps need to post that suite of sudo commands in a post-deploy-hook ..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`$ cat .ebextensions/foo.config
container_commands:
  01_foo:
    command: |
      sudo chmod -R 777 /full/path/to/storage
      cd /to/directory/for/php
      php artisan passport:install
    leader_only: false
    ignoreErrors: false`

`container_commands` run relatively last, use the ## (01) to sort it into your custom order. see `/var/log/eb-activity.log` to tweak

Comment: It seems like these commands are executed but it's not working properly...